# using symfony bundles

Tags: symfony, bundle

I am new to symfony, so may be it's not a good question...

1. If any symfony1 plugin works in Symfony2?
2. How to install new bundle in Symfony2 or where can I learn about it?
3. Is there any good place to look after bundles?
4. Is there a bundle for resizing images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No. Symfony2 is completely different. But some symfony1 modules have been ported to Symfony2.
2. Usually each bundle provides instructions for setting it up. Take a look at [ElnurBlowfishPasswordEncoderBundle](https://github.com/elnur/ElnurBlowfishPasswordEncoderBundle) for an example.
3. [KnpBundles](http://knpbundles.com/) is the de-facto place for searching bundles.
4. http://knpbundles.com/search?q=imag

Comment: I tried to install some bundle, but when i use `php bin/vendors install` I get the message  Your project seems to be based on a Standard Edition that includes vendors. Try to run ./bin/vendors install --reinstall

Comment: "caused a lot of problems" such as?

Comment: It started to install all the bundles again (and of course it took a long time), then the project stopped working ... I saw only part of the packages were installed. Actually, I do not remember exactly what were the problems, because it was long ago. But if it's meaningful, I can back up now the symfony and try to do it. [In any case, I've seen online, that other people that caused problems http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=38894]

Comment: Sorry. Seems I was wrong. Now I made reinstall and it works properly. But I do not understand why I should install all bundles again if I only want to install one package ?